# Lista auto ajustável no xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

Eu tenho uma lista de `BitmapImage` e queria que ela aparecesse da seguinte forma, 3 imagens por linha, caso não preencha uma linha, fique um espaço em branco no final.

Por exemplo, eu tenho minha lista com 10 imagens pequenas e quero que ela apareça 3 imagens nas 3 primeiras linhas e uma imagem na quarta linha colada na esquerda e o restante um espaço em branco.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O que você tem até o momento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize no XAML um **UniformGrid** e informe a quantidade de colunas que você deseja (neste caso são 3 colunas) no campo **Columns**.

```
<UniformGrid Name="gridImagens" Columns="3">

</UniformGrid>
```

Agora no código C# *crie controles de imagem cujo source seja as imagens que você quer mostrar* no grid e adicione esses controles à coleção de filhos do UniformGrid. (Uma boa prática é limpar a lista de filhos do UniformGrid antes de carregar as imagens, para assim assegurar que as imagens não ficarão duplicadas).

```
 private void CarregueListaDeImagens()
 {
     gridImagens.Children.Clear();

     var arquivosDeImagem = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Ulysses\Pictures\TesteUniformGrid");

     foreach (var imagem in arquivosDeImagem)
     {
         var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagem));

         var controleImagem = new Image();
         controleImagem.Source = bitmap;

         gridImagens.Children.Add(controleImagem);
     }
 }
```

Segue abaixo o **resultado final quando se carrega 10 imagens**. As imagens são carregadas de 3 em 3 em cada linha, deixando espaços em branco no final quando o número de imagens carregadas não é múltiplo de 3, de acordo com o que você especificou na sua pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]